# How to cast ObjectId in Postman Body

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, mongodb-query, postman, mern

I am making post request using Postman but geting this error:

```
  validation failed: _id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value &quot
```

I am trying in this way:

[image]

My _id type is ObjectId in Schema:

[image]

So,How to cast ObjectId to _id field.

Thanks.....

Comment: You can declare it as a string. For example :  _id: "632ebc90c3fc41867354a583". In your code, use it like that :  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body._id)

Comment: Are you sure you want to define `_id` field yourself. Usually this is handled by mongodb internally. Nevertheless you have to instantiate an ObjectId from a string value as explained in the previous comment. The only exception is, when you use `findById[...]`. In this case you could also pass string values to the function as mongoose will take care of the casting.